# Volver a ejecutar el TRY si CATCH da error

Tags: javascript

Pues eso, necesito que si salta el catch, se vuelva a ejecutar el try en plan bucle.

```
    try{

miFuncion();

}catch(Error){

    alert("¡Introduce un número entre 1 y 99!");

};
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado utilizar un bucle alrededor del `try`? Podrías agregar un `while` para lograr lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás prefieras utilizar un bucle en lugar de un try catch

```js
do {
 alert("¡Introduce un número entre 1 y 99!");
}
while(!miFunction())
```